# WP Meta query for a custom post type based on agent name

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm hoping you can help me out and give me a tip on something I'm trying to achieve and failing miserably.

I'm working on a WordPress real-estate theme - Reales. Here is the link to the website,

What I'm trying to achieve is to have sections with featured properties, for each agent separately, like an agent page where I can his listing, the page I'm creating is outside the wp-content I did link it with wp-load so I have display the properties but they are random, not specific for an agent.

So in order to do that, I need to create a query that gets the posts.

```
     <?php
```

global $post;
$orig_post = $post;

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author_name' => 'property-agent',
     'meta_key'      => 3279, 
    'meta_value'        => 'agent name', 
    'meta_compare'  => 'LIKE' 

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find the solution it was near to the question I just need to search with the id of the agent and the query should be like that :

```
  <?php  global $post;
   $orig_post = $post;
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);  $args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'property_agent',
        'value'   => '400529',
        'compare' => 'like'
    )
);
```